# Graph of $(e^x-1)/x$ as x->0

Tags: graphing-functions, calculator

This question may be as much computer science as math, as I don't believe the reason is mathematical; however an odd thing a classmate of mine pointed out: if you look at a graph of the function in question on any kind of graphing calculator, and get really really REALLY close to 0, the graph starts oscillating(ex:http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+y+%3D+%28e%5Ex-1%29%2Fx+from+-1x10%5E-14+to+1x10%5E-14&x=-1244&y=-71)

I was wondering if anyone could offer an explanation as to why this phenomenon occurs.

Comment: Rounding error.

Comment: If you ask a calculator to compute the function, a naive evaluation will produce a subtractive cancellation between $e^x$ and $1$ for arguments close to zero, which would amplify any rounding errors in $e^x$ into the oscillations you report.

Comment: In a system like Mathematica you can specifically require that the program keep more digits of precision. That will eliminate this effect, up to your specified precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you take your function on Wolfram Alpha, try replacing $-14$ by $-15$.  You will see that Wolfram Alpha evaluates at a few discrete points, then connects the dots in some way.  Hence, your viewing window is right up against the limits of computation, and rounding error (as @hardmath describes in more detail in the comments) becomes amplified.